# rotate my iphone app in ipad when rotate option is enabled

Tags: iphone, ios, rotation, uiinterfaceorientation, autorotate

I want to rotate my iphone application in ipad if I rotate the ipad
what I use in my code is :

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    return (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
}
```

and I check both portrait and landscape:
[image]

and the plist file:

[image]

my application device family is only iphone, and appears as an iphone in ipad device

But it doesn't rotate, please correct my code above, thank you

Comment: Are you using iOS 5 ?

Answer (score 0):

you ask it ? ;

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
}

Put it into the code if try again.

Answer (score 0):

In the .plist file you only specify your startup orientations. After that every view controller can implement shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: in which the view controller is "asked" if a rotation to another orientation is acceptable. In the standard template for iPad apps this always returns YES and thus allows all orientations. In your case you might only return YES when the given orientation is UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft, although you should have a look if you can support both landscape orientations as Apple human interface guidelines strongly suggest to at least support both landscape orientations if one is supported.

Note that every view controller in your app has to specify its own orientations as it may make sense to have some views more restricted than others.

For further information on this have a look at:

Supporting orrientations for iPad apps: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1689/_index.html

Why won't my UIViewController rotate with the device: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1688/_index.html

UIViewController class reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html